# NumPy array of arrays to PyOpenCL array of vecs

Tags: python, numpy, pyopencl

I have a NumPy array which contains arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
someArray = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Now, I'd like to convert this array to an OpenCL array of vec4s in order to do something with it. For example:

```
context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue()
program = cl.Program("""
    __kernel void multiplyByTwo(__global const float32* someArrayAsOpenCLType, __global float32* result) {
        gid = get_global_id(0);
        vector = someArrayAsOpenCLType[gid];
        result[gid] = vector * 2;
    }
""").build()

someArrayAsOpenCLType = # something with someArray
result = # some other thing
program.multiplyByTwo(queue, someArray.shape, None, someArrayAsOpenCLType, result)
```

What do I do to convert someArray to someArrayAsOpenCLType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in `someArray` is stored in host's memory and these data has to be copied to a device's buffer memory (`someArrayAsOpenCLType`).

The kernel executes on device and stores the results on a device buffer (pre-allocated: `resultAsOpenCLType`).

After the execution, the program may get the results from device's buffer back to host memory (e.g.: `cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, resultAsOpenCLType)`).

Follow a simple example (but maybe there are other ways to do this):

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

# Context
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
# Create queue
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

someArray = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
]).astype(np.float32)

print ""
print("Input:")
print(someArray)
print("------------------------------------")

# Get mem flags
mf = cl.mem_flags

# Create a read-only buffer on device and copy 'someArray' from host to device
someArrayAsOpenCLType = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=someArray)

# Create a write-only buffer to get the result from device
resultAsOpenCLType = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, someArray.nbytes)

# Creates a kernel in context
program = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void multiplyByTwo(__global const float4 *someArrayAsOpenCLType, __global float4 *resultAsOpenCLType) {
        int gid = get_global_id(0);

        float4 vector = someArrayAsOpenCLType[gid];
        resultAsOpenCLType[gid] =  vector * (float) 2.0;
}
""").build()

# Execute
program.multiplyByTwo(queue, someArray.shape, None, someArrayAsOpenCLType, resultAsOpenCLType)

# Creates a buffer for the result (host memory)
result = np.empty_like(someArray)

# Copy the results from device to host
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, resultAsOpenCLType)

print("------------------------------------")
print("Output")
# Show the result
print (result)
```

After the execution (with option `0`):

```
Choose platform:
[0] <pyopencl.Platform 'Intel(R) OpenCL' at 0x858ea0>
[1] <pyopencl.Platform 'Experimental OpenCL 2.0 CPU Only Platform' at 0x872880>
[2] <pyopencl.Platform 'NVIDIA CUDA' at 0x894a80>
Choice [0]:
Set the environment variable PYOPENCL_CTX='' to avoid being asked again.

Input:
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.]]
------------------------------------
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py:59: CompilerWarning: Built kernel retrieved from cache. Original from-sour
ce build had warnings:
Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz' on 'Intel(R) OpenCL' at 0x86ca30> succeeded, but said:

Compilation started
Compilation done
Linking started
Linking done
Device build started
Device build done
Kernel <multiplyByTwo> was not vectorized
Done.
  warn(text, CompilerWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py:59: CompilerWarning: From-binary build succeeded, but resulted in non-empt
y logs:
Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz' on 'Intel(R) OpenCL' at 0x86ca30> succeeded, but said:

Device build started
Device build done
Reload Program Binary Object.
  warn(text, CompilerWarning)
------------------------------------
Output
[[  2.   4.   6.   8.]
 [ 10.  12.  14.  16.]]
```

Some tutorials about OpenCL on Intel's site:

[Intel - OpenCL™ Tutorials](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-tutorials)

Comment: Thank you! I was hesitant about the fact that I could actually retrieve a float4 from someArrayAsOpenCLType if I simply feeded it to a buffer, so your answer is spot on!